# How to control downstream pipeline's interactive input in upstream pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have an upstream pipeline which is calling another downstream pipeline

```
build job: "/org/projectA/master",
  parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'variable', value: 'value']],
  wait: true
```

In my downstream pipeline, there is a step to ask for approve

```
input "Deploy to prod?"
```

Currently the job is paused in the downstream pipeline waiting for approve, but in my main job (upstream pipeline), it is just waiting for sub pipeline to finish, doesn't show any message for approver. So is it possible to display the interactive input in my main pipeline? then the approver doesn't need to click to the sub pipeline to check the status.

BTW, I cannot move the **input** to main pipeline, cause there are other steps after it in the sub pipeline.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: In another words, any plugin I can use to display the downstream job step directly on upstream job console log or in blue ocean ui?

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't recommend it, but there's a way via Jenkins Remote API - 
[Jenkins input pipeline step filled via POST with CSRF - howto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827523/jenkins-input-pipeline-step-filled-via-post-with-csrf-howto)

```
curl -X POST -H "Jenkins-Crumb:${JENKINS_CRUMB}" -d json='{"parameter": {"name": "${PARAMETER_NAME}", "value": "${PARAMETER_VALUE}"}}' -d proceed='${SUBMIT_CAPTION}' 'http://j${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_ID}/input/${INPUT_ID}/submit'
```

The question would be how would you run this? A new input in the upstream job? Run when?

It might be more useful to divide the downstream job into two and run the actual deploy only when user accepts the input in the upstream job.

Comment: hi @hakamairi, thanks for your reply. I cannot move the waiting for approve input to upstream, because there are couple upstream jobs will call this downstream job, and we would like to lock this downstream job(for someone to approve) to allow only one job run at a time. In another words, in jenkins console or blue ocean, we cannot view the downstream job steps details in upsteam.

Comment: Hi, yeah I don't know if there's a way to propagate those, and since the platform doesn't support this I this you would need to write a plugin of sorts. Even then another pipeline is not a step or anything so how would it look like in UI? I think you need to change the problem in order to make it solvable.